# Rollback in multiples querys using JDBC spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, rollback, spring-data-jdbc

i have this problem, when i execute two querys in same function, if the second query throw exception and not working, the first query keep yor result in database, both querys are insert in ddbb **EXAMPLE:**

```
public void myFunction(){
  query1(); //insert data in ddbb
  query2(); // also try to insert data in ddbb but not working and throw exception
}
```

in this case i need do **rollback** in **both** querys but currently the query1 doesn't rollback and keep his insert in datbase.

I am using **spring data JDBC**

thanks and sorry for my english, not is my native language

Comment: the @Transactional solution works but only if I comment on the class where I have the aspects, do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could annotate your method with `@Transactional`, which would instruct Spring to rollback the entire method in the event of an exception:

```
@Transactional
public void myFunction(){
    // insert data in ddbb
    // also try to insert data in ddbb but not working and throw exception
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but only if I comment on the class where I have the aspects, do you know why?

Comment: This doesn't work, the annotation needs to be on the method or class calling these two methods.

Comment: the Annotation needs to be on the first method which init the querys to envelop all queries and allow rollback